# How To Understand THE Following Code Snippet?

Tags: python-3.x

i came up with understanding confusion , what will be the right explanation for this code?

```py
a = [(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)]

result = sum(n for _,n in a)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your confusion is coming from the `,` and the fact that `sum` also accepts a second argument.

In this case, only one argument is passed to `sum` because that line is evaluated as

```
result = sum(n for (_, n) in a)
```

This line simply sums all the second elements in the list of tuples, and it is equivalent to the following:

```
list_of_tuples = [(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)]

total = 0
for (first_element, second_element) in list_of_tuples:
    total += second_element
print(total)
```

Technically `_` is a normal, valid identifier name, but the convention is to use it for values that are disregarded in the next part of the code.

Comment: Thanks, i completely understand now.

Answer (score 0):

I think another way of thinking of it is:

```
result=0
for _,n in a:
    result += n
```

You can substitute "_,n" for any other two variables like "x,y" for example.

Comment: essentially it is adding the second element in each tuple so 1 + 2 + 3 = 6

Comment: Thanks, yeah i understand its tuple unpacking in sum.